# How to show convergence of this infinite series?

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble showing that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{en^{n + 1/2} - (n + 1)^{n + 1/2}}{(n+1)^{n + 1/2}}$$
converges. Can anyone help? All of the standard techniques I have been trying have been failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing numerator and denominator by $n^{n+\frac12}$, you can write the $n$th term of the series as
$$
\frac{e - (1+\frac 1n)^{n+\frac12}}{(1+\frac 1n)^{n+\frac12}}.
$$
Now, if $x\ge 0$, expanding the logarithm as a Taylor series with remainder gives
$$
\log(1+x)=x-\frac 12 x^2 + \epsilon(x) x^3, \qquad 0\le \epsilon(x)\le \frac 13,
$$
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+\frac 1n)^{n+\frac12}&=&\exp\left( (n+\frac12) \log(1+\frac 1n)\right)\\
&=& \exp \left((n+\frac 12) (\frac 1n -\frac 1 {2n^2} + \epsilon(\frac 1n) \frac{1}{n^3})\right)\\
&=& \exp (1 + O(\frac{1}{n^2}))\\
&=& e + O(\frac{1}{n^2}).
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, the $n$th term of the series is $O(n^{-2})$, so it converges.

Comment: Wouldnt the $n$th term be $\frac{-O(n^{-2})}{e+O(n^{-2})}$

Comment: Well, frankly I know nothing about big o notation or how to use it - especially how to use it in infinite series. I have a hard time grasping what it means or how to manipulate its expressions.

Comment: $O(n^{-2})/(e+O(n^{-2}))=O(n^{-2})$.

Comment: Whoa. Is this a standard trick? (Taking exp log, then expanding the log as a Taylor series) How did you know to do that?

Comment: It's a standard trick.